# Why trigger query fails in the sqlite - QT here -?

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, qt, sqlite

I am a beginner in the SQL. I am using sqlite , QT - on embedded systems. I want to put a trigger here. The trigger is that whenever the primary key Id is greater than 32145, then channelNum=101 should be set. I want to set the attrib name - text also, but I got the compilation issue. I believe that the setting of trigger is the part of DDL - Data definition language. Please let me know that if I am wrong here. Here is my create db code. I get the sql query error.  Also please do suggest how to set the text - attrib = "COmedy".

```
/** associate db with query **/
        QSqlQuery query ( m_demo_db );
        /** Foreign keys are disabled by default in sqlite **/
        /** Here is the pragma to turn them on first **/
        query.exec("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
        if ( false == query.exec())
        {
            qDebug()<<"Pragma failed";
        }
        /** Create Table for storing user preference LCN for DTT **/
        qDebug()<<"Create Table postcode.db";
        query.prepare(" CREATE TABLE  dttServiceList (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, attrib varchar(20), channelNum integer )" );
        if ( false == query.exec())
        {
            qDebug()<<"Create dttServiceList table failed";
        }
        /** Try placing trigger here **/
        triggerQuery = "CREATE TRIGGER upd_check BEFORE INSERT ON dttServiceList \
                 FOR EACH ROW \
                 BEGIN  \
                IF Id > 32145 THEN SET channelNum=101; \
              END IF; \
                END; ";
         query.prepare(triggerQuery);
         if ( false == query.exec())
         {
             qDebug()<<"Trigger failed !!";
             qDebug() << query.lastError();
         }
```

Also, how to set the text name in the trigger - I want to SET attrib = "Comedy". I am using qt - sqlite. Thanks! for your replies.

Comment: ID is a primary key and I suppose you cant use this way.

Comment: if its not auto_incremented and you are passing the id in the insert query then try using `IF NEW.Id >` instead of `Id >`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has neither an IF nor a SET statement.

As shown in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html), you can use only UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE/SELECT statements in a trigger.

A condition for the entire trigger can be implemented with a WHEN clause.

You cannot change the values being inserted directly; you have to update that records afterwards:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER upd_check
AFTER INSERT ON dttServiceList
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.Id > 32145
BEGIN
    UPDATE dttServiceList
    SET channelNum = 101
    WHERE Id = NEW.Id;
END;
```

Comment: How to assign the text here - attrib = "Comedy"

Comment: Thanks! I got the answer. Check here. However, I couldn't understand that control flow diagram.   triggerQuery = "CREATE TRIGGER upd_check \
                AFTER INSERT ON dttServiceList \
                FOR EACH ROW \
                WHEN NEW.Id > 32145 \
                BEGIN \
                    UPDATE dttServiceList \
                    SET channelNum = 101 , attrib = 'Comedy' \
                    WHERE Id = NEW.Id; \
                    END";